# Pyspark - How to force spark to infer schema again when reading from Parquet files which already has (wrong) schema?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data in S3 saved in Parquet file format but some of the data types are wrong.
Since schema is already inside Parquet files - how do I force to 'infer' schema again (ignoring current schema) into Dataframe?

Current code is:

```
df_raw = spark.read.parquet("s3://myfolder/data/")
df_raw.printSchema() -> Wrong Data Types
```

I would like to have `df_fixed` with same data and correct (inferred) schema.

Thanks.